# How to check if the sent email delivered or not?

Tags: php

i'm working on a project and a task was assigned to me to check if the email was sent , delivered and opened , actually i don't know how to check if it was delivered or not, any suggestions .

Comment: It is not the "role" of PHP to know if an email has been delivered or not, PHP can only know and also with marginal accuracy whether the remote SMTP server accepted the email or not

Comment: i used SMTP and telnet commands inside php class and all sent mails returned with 250 accepted without any delivery even the mail address book was false .

Comment: If both parties are using MS Outlook then you might be able to plugin to the COM interface (I think its COM) to find the necessary status flags otherwise forget it.

Comment: In Microsoft Outlook / Exchange groups mail messages can be sent with a "return receipt".  The recipient must use the Outlook client to open the message so a receipt can be sent.  As far as the rest of the world, it depends on the email system that is used, I don't think you will find a general solution.  many, many, many mail eco-systems have decided that return receipts are a waste of time, ridiculously unreliable, and unportable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is impossible.

Think it as a real life example.

If you send a letter to someone. You also don't know if he will receives it. Unless he calls you and says "hey, i've your letter"

And also, he has to call you, if he has read the letter which sounds strange, don't you think?

It would be all possible if you've a own message service thing, or application like e.g. facebook. They can store the fact that you've opened the "mail" but than it isn't actually a mail but rather a messege to another user. And doesn't use email adresses nor emails

Comment: Yeah, but even the US Postal Service offers Return Receipt.  The postal carrier must hand deliver the message, and get the return receipt.  It's just a ridiculous way of doing business.

Comment: i think you are right , but i wondered from Hubspot system that give a fully report of the sent , delivered , opened and the mail was marked as a spam ! , or it has a high probability of error.

Comment: Well, SMTP uses TCP and what does TCP-protocol? --

E.g. your mail is split in 3 packages -
than
X sends the first package to Y --
Y sends an Acknowledge back to X --

X sends the second package to Y --
Y didn't received the packe, afte x seconds, X sends the package again --
Y receives and sends an Ack Back --

X send a new package  to Y and Y receives and sends an ack --

Thus actually SMTP will promise you that the sender receives the -- mail but there is no such thing that he will open it

Comment: Yeah your Completely right , Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to do this. It is not a feature of email.